# Cannot make new ssd drive bootable

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, lenovo-laptop

I have a new SSD drive installed on my lenovo B50 laptop and I also have an HDD from past which contains my current windows. I want to install new windows on the SSD.

I first tried to clone my current windows on it with both `AOMEI Partition Assistant` and `Paragon`. The result of both was the same; the drive was not detected as bootable and it wasn't listed on my boot options.

Then I used a bootable USB to install fresh windows, but when I select the SSD to install windows on, I get this error:

```
Windows cannot be installed on this drive. See setup logs for more information.
```

I also switched the location of SSD and HDD on the laptop to see if it's a slot problem or not. Still can't install windows on SSD and HDD windows still boots perfectly.

Note1: that my SSD is on GPT mode.

Note2: there is no problem on writing on SSD or reading files from it.

Note3: the USB windows setup is not corrupted. I have installed on several laptops from it.

Note4: the boot support in BIOS is on UEFI.

Comment: Delete all partitions on the SSD and try again

Comment: Done it previously @John . No change in result

Comment: 1. "See setup logs for more information." What did the logs state? 2. As a test, try another OS, e.g. a Linux distro such as Ubuntu that can be installed in~5 minutes to HDD.

Comment: I couldn't find the logs any where @DrMoishePippik , but I changed the physical location of SSD and HDD which fixed the problem. please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the location of the SSD. After I changed the location of HDD and SSD, I  still could not boot from SSD. I checked the physical contact and detach/attach the SSD one more time. It worked finally.